# C# Accessing dotnetBrowser from a UserControl

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

So essentially I'm using the dotNetBrowser for a project that i'm loading into a panel on my main form, and I have a button in a usercontrol for user input so it can interact with the browser. Here's what I have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public BrowserView browserView = new WinFormsBrowserView();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.panel1.Controls.Add((Control)browserView);
        browserView.Browser.LoadURL("URL TO BE LOADED");

        browserView.Browser.FinishLoadingFrameEvent += delegate (object sender, FinishLoadingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsMainFrame)
                {
                // Do stuff when loaded
                } else return;
            }
        };

    }
}
```

That works fine, in my usercontrol.cs I have:

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BrowserView br = (this.Parent as Form1).Controls["browserView"] as BrowserView;
        br.Browser.LoadURL("NEW URL");   
    }
```

So that when the button is clicked it can load a new url. But this is throwing a null exception.

Basically I need these two components to be able to pass information on to eachother. The method I've used worked fine for other Form1 controls, but not the browser it seems.

Any advice?

Comment: "throwing a null exception" is not a very helpful bit of information. Where does the stacktrace say the error occurs?

Comment: `(this.Parent as Form1)`.  The BrowserView control is in the Panel's Control Collection, not the Form's direct Control collection.

Comment: It occurs at "br.Browser.LoadURL("NEW URL");"

Comment: LarsTech, whether the browser is loaded in the panel or not, it throws the same exception

Comment: Your code didn't give the control a name, so `Controls["browserView"]` won't work unless you name that control.

Comment: It's instantiated as:     public BrowserView browserView = new WinFormsBrowserView();

In the form.cs, shouldn't it be named "browserView" ?

Comment: No, it won't have a name unless you give it one: `BrowserView browserView = new WinFormsBrowserView() { Name = "browserView" };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `browserView` is a name of the public variable, so you can simply use`(this.Parent as Form1).browserView` to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Your are adding `browserView` to `Form1.panel1`, but trying to get it from `(this.Parent as Form1)`.

You don't need to search for `BrowserView` when you have explicit reference to it. I suggest giving this reference to the user control. User control having the knowledge of the innards of the hosting form means that information is flowing in the wrong direction.

Names of controls are given to them by IDE, and are empty when controls are created in code.